# Java integer to fixed length byte array

Tags: java, integer, byte

How can I convert an integer between 0 and 65k to fixed length of two bytes? as an example

2   would be `00000000 00000010`

~65k would be `11111111 11111111`

and all that in a byte array

Comment: I edited my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java has the **short** data type, this is a 2 bytes integer. You cast the integer to short.

```
int a = 1;
short b = (short)a;
```

If you want the bytes of the integer you can use **ByteBuffer**

```
byte[] bytes = ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort((short)intnumber).array();
```

Or if you want the binary format you can just use **toBinaryString** method of the Integer.

```
int x = 2;
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(x));
```

Comment: I think the middle one is what I'm looking for, but it throws an BufferOverflow Exception in my case

Comment: Yes, Just use ByteBuffer.allocate(2).putShort((short)1);

Answer (score 0):

When `x` is your number between 0 and 65,535 just use

```
new byte[] { (byte) (x >> 8), (byte) x }
```

to create a byte array containing the value as two bytes in big-endian format.